# How to access form elements in table via getValue()?

Tags: 8, forms

I'm trying to do so using array indices. Say, we have

```php
$form['mytable'] = array(
'#type' => 'table',
'#header' => array(t('a'), t('b')));

$form['mytable'][1]['a'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#required' => true));

$form['mytable'][1]['b'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#required' => true));
```

What am I doing: `$form_state->getValue('mytable[1][b]');`, and it's not working. And how to pass such a field to `setErrorByName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't setting `#tree` to `TRUE`, you just need to use the following code.

```
$a = $form_state->getValue('a');
$b = $form_state->getValue('b');
```

The same is true for `setErrorByName()`: You use `'a'` and `'b'` as names of the fields.

For example, [`CommentAdminOverview::buildForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21Form%21CommentAdminOverview.php/function/CommentAdminOverview%3A%3AbuildForm/8.2.x) contains the following code.

```
  // Build an 'Update options' form.
  $form['options'] = array(
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#title' => $this->t('Update options'),
    '#open' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('container-inline')),
  );

  // Omissis.

  $form['options']['operation'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => $this->t('Action'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#default_value' => 'publish',
  );
  $form['options']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Update'),
  );
```

The submission handler ([`CommentAdminOverview::submitForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21Form%21CommentAdminOverview.php/function/CommentAdminOverview%3A%3AsubmitForm/8.2.x)), accesses the value submitted for `$form['options']['operation']` using the following code.

```
$operation = $form_state->getValue('operation');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access `$form_state` values like below

`$values = $form_state->getValues();`

If you are printing `$values` then you will get

```
Array
(
    [mytable] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [a] => Value of a
                    [b] => Value of b
                )

        )
)
```

`setErrorByName()` function can be used while validating the elements.

Comment: If the OP is not setting `#tree` to `TRUE`, it is probable the output is quite different.

Answer (score 0):

The form table is going to give you a structured array (like Arun stated).

I find it easier to just get the full array for the table from $form_state and then get the specific data from that array.

```
$mytable = $form_state->getValue('mytable');
$a = $mytable[1]['a'];
$b = $mytable[1]['b'];
```

But really, you'll probably end up looping through all the values in the table:

```
foreach($form_state->getValue('mytable') as $i => $row){
   $row_number = $i;
   $a = $row['a'];
   $b = $row['b'];
}
```

Finally, the form validation is a little confusing. In the setErrorByName method, Drupal basically converts the string name in the validation to the array structure of the multidimensional form array by exploding the string on ']['. So to validate a specific value in your table, you could do this:

```
$mytable = $form_state->getValue('mytable');
if ($mytable[1]['a'] == 'invalid'){
  $form_state->setErrorByName('mytable][1][a', 'there was an error');
}
```

Or again, you will probably want to check each row of your table doing something like this:

```
$mytable = $form_state->getValue('mytable');
foreach($form_state->getValue('mytable') as $i => $row){
  if ($row['a'] == 'invalid'){
    $form_state->setErrorByName('mytable]['.$i.'][a', 'there was an error');
  }
}
```

One last thing. In Drupal 7, you need to set #tree to true for table forms or else it does not build a multidimensional array. But with the table form element in Drupal 8, this is not necessary. https://www.drupal.org/node/1876710